# Showing directional line symbol in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, line, direction, arcview-3

Is this possible in ArcGIS to have variable number of arrows on the line to show direction?

This is an ArcGIS example, where I can have fixed (1,**2,3**,4,5...) number of arrows and it stays the same doesn't matter what the line length is. First and last always stick to the end, doesn't help with network mapping, where there is usually the node to show. Having just one in the middle is never enough, check line at the right...
[image]

No such issues with ArcView 3:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an overlapping Marker Symbol line and make the Template as shown.  For the marker symbol I used the Dimension Style set Solid Triangle 2 which points to the right.  I resized it down from 18 points to 12 points.

[image: Mark Line Symbol Template]

Now I have a question for you.  For the line ends marker I tried using the dual arrows and a green circle with a dot like you showed, but the circles are not centered on the ends of the lines.  Are your green circle marker symbols at the line ends tied to the lines themselves or are they tied to extracted points from the line ends?  (Note:  The lines in the picture below do not split at every intersection for all lines).

[image: Line Markers with end circles]

Comment: Superb! I was struggling with this for a long time, thank you. Green dots at the ends of the line are from separate point feature class. I do networks modelling, it requires lines (conduits) and points (nodes) and it is all about flow direction. This is why arrow thing was so annoying.