# How to quickly visualize polyline direction?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, editing, line

I am wondering if there is a quick method with arcgis desktop to view the edited direction of a large group of polylines?

I'm essentially wondering if anyone knows of a way to achieve the Editor > Construct Parallel view of one line, but instead for groups of lines?

ArcGIS v10.1 ArcInfo License

Apologies if this question has already been asked, agreed it is a bonehead question. All the best!

Comment: Change the symbology to include an arrow at the end

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112286/showing-directional-line-symbol-in-arcgis-for-desktop

Comment: Thanks a bunch, sorry to waste your time @Midavalo, you're doing a great job!