# How to show line symbol (arrow) independently of line length in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, line, direction

I am manually creating a polyline layer in ESRI geodatabase. Lines are of 2 vertices (start-end), variable length but all very short. I am using directional symbol with arrow at the end (or middle). And I have a small annoying problem: I cannot see the shortest lines. The arrow just disappears when its size is less than the line at that scale. What I get is this: 
[image]

And I have troubles to see short lines like the upper two especially when I add more layers to the map, because I am creating the lines based on other geodatabase layers.

Increasing the width is not good because it shows a perpendicular expansion of a real line. I just want ArcGIS to show me the arrow symbol always, no matter the visible length of the line. I was searching in Symbol properties as it was advised also here 
[Showing directional line symbol in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112286/showing-directional-line-symbol-in-arcgis-for-desktop)
but could not find the solution. When I google, I find only opposite situations (people want to show different symbols depending on the length). Converting line ends to points to show symbols is not possible because I am editing the layer and adding new lines. So I really need to see them well, and their direction. What I want is this: 
[image]

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop. Maybe this is a fault of ArcGIS? Because QGIS is showing arrows as I need:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps use point symbol as described in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214720/points-along-one-or-more-lines-at-a-time-with-rotation/214801#214801

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a triangle marker point style at the end of line "end".  This should show at all zoom levels and show on any new features that are added.  For details see this q/a:

[Arrow Representation/Symbology](https://community.esri.com/thread/99777)

Comment: With normal symbology marker is not working well. But creating a Representation and then a marker was tough [but finally worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3O8e.png)